# Is there a 'contains' like equivalent for JsonObject (not just for JsonArray)?

Tags: karate

I'm getting a response that is a JsonObject (not a JsonArray) that can have a dynamic set of *key.value* pairs. I do not know ahead of time what the specific collection of *key.values* pairs will be for any given request.

I do have reasonable knowledge of "all possible" key.value pairs. Is it possible to test (match) that the key.value pairs in a given response are "contained" in a "super-set" of possible key.value pairs?

Here is a basic idea:

```
* def response = {"number": "1234567890", "name": "a_name"}
* def super_set = {"location": "#string", "number": "#number", "depart": "#string", "name": "#string"}
* match response contains super_set
```

The `match` would be `true` if both the keys in the `response` are *contained* in the `super_set` and each key matches the *fuzzy match* marker.

I've read the docs regarding `contains`, `contains any`, `contains only`, etc, but it appears they are only appropriate for Arrays.

What I actually think I need is the inverse logic:

```
* match super_set contains response
```

but I'm just not sure how to acomplish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without Java:

```
* def response = {"number": "1234567890", "name": "a_name"}
* def super_set = {"location": "#string", "number": "#number", "depart": "#string", "name": "#string"}
* def expected = {}
* eval karate.forEach(response, function(k){ if (super_set[k]) expected[k] = super_set[k] })
* match response == expected
```

EDIT: this will be made easier using a new `karate.filterKeys()` API in version 0.9.4 onwards

```
* def schema = { a: '#string', b: '#number', c: '#boolean' }
* def response = { a: 'x', c: true }
# very useful for validating a response against a schema "super-set"
* match response == karate.filterKeys(schema, response)
* match karate.filterKeys(response, 'b', 'c') == { c: true }
* match karate.filterKeys(response, ['a', 'b']) == { a: 'x' }
```

Comment: Not certain what my config issue is but when I try this I get a KarateException "no step-definition method match found for: karate.forEach(response, function(k){ expected[k] = super_set[k] })". Using com.intuit.karate:karate-core:0.9.2. In fact the only way I can access the karate object is by "wrapping" it like this:
`* def isNumber = function (x) { return karate.match(x, '#number'); }`

Comment: @kpschmidt my bad. you need an `eval` which will be optional from 0.9.4 onwards. edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. A much cleaner/direct solution then calling out to Java.

Comment: @kpschmidt thanks, I'm now convinced this can be made easier, see https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/810

Comment: @ Peter Thomas Just an observation, the assignment `expected[k] = super_set[k]` places the key `k` in the `expected` object with a value of `null` if the key _does **not** exist_ in the `super_set` object. I was expecting the key.value pair to not be present in the `expected` object if not present in the `superset` object.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by calling out to Java, passing actual response and super-set, and returning map matching keys in actual response but with values (fuzzy match markers) from super-set.